# CakePHP: How do I render multiple elements with parameters from a controller?

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm working with CakePHP 1.3. I'm making an AJAX call where I want the server to return some HTML that corresponds to several of rows of results that I can throw inside a `<div>`. I have the template for a single row stored as an element called 'library_track'. The element requires variables 'id', 'artist' and 'name' to be passed to it. I would like my function `getResults()` to return a block of HTML that is composed of HTML from several elements.

Can anyone show me what this code would look like please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as usual, you'll probably have to loop through the results in your view:

Controller:

```
function getResults() {
    // here be dragons
    $this->set(compact('results'));
}
```

View /foo/getresults.ctp:

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo $this->element('library_track', array('id' => $result['Result']['id'], ...));
}
```