# Ajax method render multiple elements

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I have an ajax method that takes in an array of ids for tags and does some processing to make sure the tags aren't already used. Then I need to send HTML back to the client so I can render the tags with javascript. With just one tag it's fairly trivial to call

```
$this->render('/Element/tag');
```

from the controller, as the body of the response generated by 'render' will contain the html for the element. How do I convert my array of tags into each element and send that in a response back to the client?

Comment: According to [this answer on another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16092328/7100404) I shouldn't be sending back html like this and should only send data and build my element in the javascript. But then what good is having the element template around? How can I leverage the template in this use case?

Comment: I'd generally disagree with that sentiment, it's reductive to the point of NEVER rendering HTML via CakePHP (why not build the whole app in javascript and send literally everything in JSON?!). It's a valid but different way of doing things is all. CakePHP can also make use of [view routing](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#routing-file-extensions) to allow the same endpoint to serve HTML sometimes and JSON data at other times.

Answer (score 0):

You can only call `render` once - think of it as simply indicating which "view" you wish to use at the end of your Controller code.

If you need a view that renders multiple tags, you could just define a new view, for example `/src/Template/Tags/tags.ctp`.

You can pass anything you want to your view (the `Tags/tags.ctp` file), including an array of tags:

```
$tags = ['Tag 1', 'Tag 2'];

$this->set('tags', $tags);

$this->render('Tags/tags');
```

Then inside the `tags.ctp`, use the tag Element to render each one:

```
<?php foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    echo $this->element('tags',  [
        "tag" => $tag
    ]);
}
```

Comment: This is the same as [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4405533/7100404), and while it may work, it isn't very DRY. Is there a solution that is DRYer?

Comment: The whole point of Elements is to define short bits of reusable HTML that you can insert into Views .. they are tools to keep repeating bits of code accessible from multiple Views, a very DRY principle. What part is this "repeating" you'd like to avoid?

Comment: I now have an element for rendering a single tag and another element for rendering multiple tags. I want to be able to send data back sort of like render() for multiple tags and just use the one 'tag' element.

Comment: You're still confusing [Elements](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#elements) with Views -- probably because you "hijacked" an element in your question _as_ the View. If you follow the normal convention, you'd create a View template instead (matching the Controller's name, ex. `TagsController::processTags` will look automatically for `src/Template/Tags/processTags.ctp`) then the call to `render` isn't needed. Use the same View for either a bunch of Tags or one tag, by setting it with `$this->set`. Elements shouldn't _usually_ be called from a Controller. Elements suppliment Views.